# Storing characters as single bytes in java

Tags: java, char, byte

I read that we should use Reader/Writer for reading/writing character data and InputStream/OutputStream for reading/writing binary data. Also, in java characters are 2 bytes. I am wondering how the following program works. It reads characters from standard input stores them in a single byte and prints them out. How are two byte characters fitting into one byte here?

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week10/06.html

Answer (score 6):

The comment explains it pretty clearly:

```
// Notice that although a byte is read, an int
// with value between 0 and 255 is returned.
// Then this is converted to an ISO Latin-1 char 
// in the same range before being printed.
```

So basically, this *assumes* that the incoming byte represents a character in ISO-8859-1.

If you use a console with a different encoding, or perhaps provide a character which isn't *in* ISO-8859-1, you'll end up with problems.

Basically, this is *not* good code.

Answer (score 1):

Java stores characters as 2 bytes, but for normal ASCII characters the actual data fits in one byte.  So as long as you can assume the file being read there is ASCII then that will work fine, as the actual numeric value of the character fits in a single byte.

Comment: Thanks, Herms. I understand that normal ASCII characters can fit into one byte. But they would still be stored as two bytes right?

Comment: When read into java the value will be stored in 2 bytes, in that the char object will have 2 bytes assigned to it.  However, only the first byte of that will be non-zero, as the value will only take up that many bits.